# For Flutter web: how to detect html.window.location.href change in onGenerateRoute

Tags: flutter, web, url, ongenerateroute

On Flutter WEB:

I use `html.window.location.href = URL` to navigate to a webview. It works very well.

The WebView has a success-URL and a cancel-URL that it leads to, depending on some user-actions on the Website.

So I end up in a new flutter route, such as either

`http://localhost:41918/#/success_page`

or

`http://localhost:41918/#/cancel_page`

I then use `onGenerateRoute` to navigate to the appropriate page according to the URL-ending.

I realized that I can put routes such as `/success_page` and `/cancel_page` into `onGenerateRoute` as follows:

```
if (settings.name == null) {
  return null;
}
var path = Uri.parse(settings.name!).path; // for all other paths...

if ((kIsWeb) && ('${html.window.location}'.contains('#'))) {
  // in case of web payment success-page
  if (('${html.window.location}'.split('#')[1] == '/success_page')) {
    path = '/success_page';
  }
  // in case of web payment cancel-page
  if (('${html.window.location}'.split('#')[1] == 'cancel_page')) {
    path = 'cancel_page';
  }
}

switch (path) {
  case '/':
     return const MainPage();
  case '/success_page':
     return const SuccessPage();
  case '/cancel_page':
     return const CancelPage();
  case '....' // more cases
}
```

So far, everyting works !

But now the issue :

Once the router navigates to, let's say, the '/success_page', I can never navigate off it anymore ! Since the URL (i.e. `html.window.location`) obviously never changes anymore. It is stuck at `http://localhost:41918/#/success_page`. And my hacky `'${html.window.location}'.split` will get stuck forever with the same page.

How can I improve it ?

I was thinking of mutating `html.window.location.href` inside the success_page (or cancel_page). But then it is never shown since the `onGenerateRoute` would immediately navigate off the page.

I could do it after a certain time. So that the user at least sees the succes (or cancel) page for a decent amount of time. But I don't like this idea too much.

I am lacking a mechanism to get the `onGenerateRoute` router-path from the `http://localhost:41918/#/success_page` URL. How do I do that ????

Or how do I get back to the normal app `http://localhost:41918` after a `html.window.location.href` has happened ??